# How to view the response for multiple indices for a single query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have created multiple indices in elasticsearch and have passed a single query to all of them. Is there any way to know,how many results came from each index?
Here is the screenshot of my elasticsearch head,showing a single aggregation applied to two indices

screenshot:
[image]

Here as in the figure you can see I have done an aggregation named "posted_time" on the indices foodfind and comics (red box 1).
But in the response window,to the right,only the results for the index "comics" is shown. How can I see the results for the other index too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use terms aggregation on the field _index for this.
Lets say you need to run the same on index-a , index-b and index-c.
You need to make the request in this pattern -

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/index-a,index-b,index-c/_search' -d '{
    "aggs" : {
       "indexStats" : {
             "terms" : {
                 "field" : "_index"
             }
        }
    }
}'
```